# visible of View in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my asp.net mvc 3 project I have 2 roles "User" and "Admin".
How to make if I logged on user I cant see View for Admin role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[Authorize(Roles="User")]` On top of every Controller class you need to.

I personally used this [tutorial](http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx) by Brian Legg

Comment: thank good tutorial, but I found solution. HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Administrators")

Comment: that will do exactly the same as that tag I suggested. So you can actually choose between them. I prefer the tag because you can put it on top of your class so you don't have to write any if-clauses. For more control, you could use that code snippet of yours.

Comment: you right, but if I log on Admin and I go to Userpanel I watch LogOn form. I dont need it :)

Comment: you can always just put the [Authorize] tag on top of every page and on the pages where only admins are allowed put the [Authorize(roles="Admin")] tag

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx)

Comment: Ignore the version it is exactly the same in newer version. You can navigate to the newer version in the docs and you will find it there.